# Python dict update from my custom dict not using my overridden methods

Tags: python, dictionary, overriding

I have a custom implementation of dict `custom_dict`, which overrides and is by-and-large supported by the native Python dict.

- I override setting (`__setitem__`) to do some preprocessing to the value, and store it in some proprietary object.
- When getting(`__getitem__`), this proprietary object is then converted to a more natural format.

All features when invoked from this `custom_dict` behave as I like.

The problem is that when you call something like `{'a': 1}.update(custom_dict({'b': 2}))`, the value for 'b' in the updated dict is the proprietary internal storage object, and not the processed value.

How does Python's native `dict.update()` work? I've overridden all the methods I could think of it using, `items`, `iteritems`, `values`, `itervalues`, `get`, and `__getitem__`, but I haven't seemed to nail any of the ones `update()` tries to access, which leads me to believe it might be using the c code.  Thoughts?

UPDATE: I just found this in the CPython source code:

```
if (PyDict_Check(b)) {
    ...
}
else {
    /* Do it the generic, slower way */
    ...
}
```

Perhaps this is a bug, and that should be `PyDict_CheckExact(b)` as shows up in various other places in the code.

Any idea how to beat this check?

Comment: Do you inherit from `dict`? Maybe not doing so would help. It looks like you don't reuse much of `dict`'s functionality anyway.

Comment: Yes, I inherit from dict.  Basically all of the methods that I have overridden explicitly call the dict.__ methods after some processing.  I figured the alternative of having a supporting dict and using the abstract base class would be worse...